# "Login failed for user 'sa' (18456)" even though I've supplied the correct credentials

Tags: python, sql-server, pyspark, centos7, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=MyServer\Server1,1433;Database=kockpit;uid=sa;pwd=*******'

con= pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cur=con.cursor()
    x = "Select TOP(50) * from [item]"
    cur.execute(x)
```

*The same credentials are working good when I am directly logging in to SQL Server.*
*Spark version 3.0.0*

Comment: When connecting to a named SQL Server instance you should supply either the instance name **or** the port number, not both. Microsoft's ODBC drivers for Linux cannot resolve instance names, but you can use the [sqlserverport](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) module to query the SQL Browser service and find the correct port for a given instance name and then use *just* the port number.

Comment: Hey buddy, 
Although I'm giving IP of the server instead of Instance name but still find myself with the same error.